# What is FormCollection argument for? Is it a dummy argument?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Up to now I have no idea why does VS provide FormCollection argument by default?

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Dinner dinner = dinnerRepository.GetDinnerById(id);

        if (dinner == null)
            return View("NotFound");
        else
            return View(dinner);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, object dummy/*, FormCollection collection*/)
    {
        Dinner temp = dinnerRepository.GetDinnerById(id);

        if (TryUpdateModel(temp))
        {
            dinnerRepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = temp.DinnerId });
        }
        else
            return View(temp);
    }
```

EDIT 1: In my experiment, any arguments other than id are dummy because they never be used in httppost Edit action method.

EDIT 2: Does TryUpdateModel use FormCollection behind the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FormCollection is how ASP.NET provides you access to the values that were just posted to your page.

You could also use a strongly typed argument and then ASP.NET MVC would use the FormCollection internally to create your strongly typed object.

Answer (score 3):

If your app receives a POST, then 99.99% of the time it will come from an HTML form. The `FormsCollection` gathers all the values in the form for you.

In ASP.NET MVC you are almost always better off using strongly typed objects though. The `DefaultModelBinder` will create them for you most of the time, and you can implement `IModelBinder` if needed if the default one doesn't do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

`FormCollection` contains your form state coming back to your server.

If you need any custom operation on the processing of your data you use `FormCollection`. Otherwise you can happily remove it.

I am using it heavily for a hierarchical model processing.

Comment: Does TryUpdateModel use FormCollection behind the scene?